# Simple automatic dependency injection in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, inversion-of-control

I'm aware that methods can be resolved automatically by Laravel within the controller:

```
//A
class ScriptsController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(Script $scripts){  // Script automatically injected
        $this->scripts = $scripts;
    }

    public function store(Request $request, $id){   // Request automatically injected
        // do something 
    }
}
```

I simply want to do the same thing with any class or method.

```
 // B1
 class MyClass extends Controller {

    public function __construct(Bar $bar){  // Bar to be automatically injected
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }

    public function doSomething(Foo $foo, $id){   // Foo to be automatically injected
        $foo->do(); 
    }
}
```

Then somewhere else

```
// B2
$class  = new MyClass();    // without an error
$class2 = new MyClass();
$class2->doSomething();    // ditto
```

There are [tutorials about this](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-method-injection) but rather than answering this directly they tend to have long explanations about how the service provider works etc.

Is there a simple way to add a line somewhere ( `Bind` perhaps ?) to have the container resolve the dependencies so that `B2` above works?

Comment: Why would you want this? Not trying to be condescending or anything, but in my experience (overly) explicit code is always better than implicit code. Should you return a year later, at least you can see what you are doing instead of going "Whaaaat...?" every time you try to debug.

Comment: This is mainly/only for classes that depend on other well tested classes to do their work and need them injected every time. The injected classes are doing complex analysis of grammatical sentence structures, and there's no chance of them changing. However, if even in this circumstance, you feel it's better to manually inject each time, I can accept that!

Comment: It's a pretty subjective thing. In my experience it's always better just to be explicit, If you're confident that implicit is clear enough, feel free to do it implicitely! @Darren Taylor's answer probably isn't exactly what you want, but it should help you get on the right track. Also good luck, sounds like an awesome application! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'd be able to do that with that particular syntax. You can have Laravel automatically inject dependencies for your class, but you'd need to resolve it out of the container in any case.

Please see the documentation here for binding: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container#binding and further down, resolving classes from the container.